# Как закрыть блок при втором клике?

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать что-бы при втором клике на круг блок закрывался https://jsfiddle.net/gr25zjox/18/ ? Спасибо

```js
let models = document.querySelectorAll('.item-circle__scene')

if (models.length > 0) {
  for (var index = 0; index < models.length; index++) {
    const model = models[index];
    model.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

      let modelSectors = document.querySelectorAll('.item-circle-block__items')
      let sectorNumb = +e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id')

      if (sectorNumb == 0) return false;
      modelSectors.forEach((sector) => {
        sector.classList.remove('_active');
      })
      modelSectors[sectorNumb - 1].classList.add('_active')
    })
  }
}

//круг//
let radius = 180;
        let countCircle = -1;
        function generateLetters(selector, text, colorCircle) {
            const letters = text.split('');
            const step = 360 / letters.length;
            countCircle = -1; // Сброс счетчика слов
            letters.forEach((l, i) => {
                const span = document.createElement('span');
                changeColor(l, span, colorCircle);
                const deg = step * i;
                span.style.transform = transform(deg, radius);
                selector.append(span);
            });
        }
        function changeColor(l, span, colorCircle) {
            if (l.toUpperCase() === l) ++countCircle; 
            span.innerText = l.toUpperCase(); 
            span.style.color = colorCircle[countCircle]; 
        }
        function transform(deg, radius = 180) {
            return `rotateY(${deg}deg) translateZ(${radius}px)`;
        }
        let circle_1 = document.querySelector('.circle_1');
        let content_1 = 'ТекстТекстТекстТекст';
        let color_1 = ['#ccba96', '#161616', '#ccba96', '#161616'];
        generateLetters(circle_1, content_1, color_1);

        let circle_2 = document.querySelector('.circle_2');
        let content_2 = 'ТекстТекстТекстТекст';
        let color_2 = ['#ccba96', '#161616', '#ccba96', '#161616'];
        generateLetters(circle_2, content_2, color_2);

        let circle_3 = document.querySelector('.circle_3');
        let content_3 = 'ТекстТекстТекстТекст';
        let color_3 = ['#ccba96', '#161616', '#ccba96', '#161616'];
        generateLetters(circle_3, content_3, color_3);
```

```css
.item-circle__scene {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
  perspective-origin: 0px -80px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  padding: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
}

.item-circle__scene:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 14;
}

.item-circle__scene:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 13;
}

.item-circle__scene:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 12;
}

.item-circle__circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate 35s linear infinite;
}

.item-circle__circle span {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #161616;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #ccba96;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  font-size: 28px;
  min-width: 60px;
  perspective-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-circle__circle::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  transform: translateZ(-5px);
}

.sector-two__description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-circle-block__items {
  display: none;
}

.item-circle-block__items._active {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #161616;
  margin: 30px 0px 10px 0px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateY(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sector-two__description description-sector-two">
   <div class="item-circle__scene">
     <div data-id="1" class="item-circle__circle circle_1"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-circle-block__items">
     какой-то текст
   </div>
   <div class="item-circle__scene">
     <div data-id="2" class="item-circle__circle circle_2"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-circle-block__items">
     какой-то текст
   </div>
   <div class="item-circle__scene">
     <div data-id="3" class="item-circle__circle circle_3"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-circle-block__items">
     какой-то текст
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну можно, изначально получить текущий элемент (по которому кликнули) и уже с ним работать

```js
let models = document.querySelectorAll('.item-circle__scene')

if (models.length > 0) {
  for (var index = 0; index < models.length; index++) {
    const model = models[index];
    model.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

      let modelSectors = document.querySelectorAll('.item-circle-block__items')
      let sectorNumb = +e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id') 

      if (sectorNumb == 0) return false;
      
      /** 1. Получаем текущий элемент */
      const currentElement = modelSectors[sectorNumb - 1];

      modelSectors.forEach((sector) => {
        /** 2. пропускаем в этерации текущий элемент */
        if (currentElement !== sector) {
            sector.classList.remove('_active');
        }
      })
      
      /** 3. по условию меняем класс */
      if (currentElement.classList.contains('_active')) {
        currentElement.classList.remove('_active')
      } else {
        currentElement.classList.add('_active')
      }
    })
  }
}


let radius = 180;
        let countCircle = -1;
        function generateLetters(selector, text, colorCircle) {
            const letters = text.split('');
            const step = 360 / letters.length;
            countCircle = -1; // Сброс счетчика слов
            letters.forEach((l, i) => {
                const span = document.createElement('span');
                changeColor(l, span, colorCircle);
                const deg = step * i;
                span.style.transform = transform(deg, radius);
                selector.append(span);
            });
        }
        function changeColor(l, span, colorCircle) {
            if (l.toUpperCase() === l) ++countCircle; //Определяем новое слово по заглавной букве и увеличиваем счетчик слов
            span.innerText = l.toUpperCase(); //В css к верхнему регистру не приводим делаем это здесь
            span.style.color = colorCircle[countCircle]; //Присваиваем цвет
        }
        function transform(deg, radius = 180) {
            return `rotateY(${deg}deg) translateZ(${radius}px)`;
        }
        let circle_1 = document.querySelector('.circle_1');
        let content_1 = 'ТекстТекстТекстТекст';
        let color_1 = ['#ccba96', '#161616', '#ccba96', '#161616'];
        generateLetters(circle_1, content_1, color_1);

        let circle_2 = document.querySelector('.circle_2');
        let content_2 = 'ТекстТекстТекстТекст';
        let color_2 = ['#ccba96', '#161616', '#ccba96', '#161616'];
        generateLetters(circle_2, content_2, color_2);

        let circle_3 = document.querySelector('.circle_3');
        let content_3 = 'ТекстТекстТекстТекст';
        let color_3 = ['#ccba96', '#161616', '#ccba96', '#161616'];
        generateLetters(circle_3, content_3, color_3);
```

```css
    .item-circle__scene {
      position: relative;
      perspective: 800px;
      perspective-origin: 0px -80px;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      padding: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
    }
  
  .item-circle__scene:nth-child(1) {
            z-index: 14;
        }
        .item-circle__scene:nth-child(2) {
            z-index: 13;
        }
    .item-circle__scene:nth-child(3) {
            z-index: 12;
        }

    .item-circle__circle {
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-bottom: 60px;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      animation: rotate 35s linear infinite;
    }

    .item-circle__circle span {
      font-weight: bold;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #161616;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #ccba96;
      padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
      font-size: 28px;
    min-width: 60px;
      perspective-origin: center;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .item-circle__circle::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
      transform: translateZ(-5px);
    }

    .sector-two__description {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .item-circle-block__items {
      display: none;
    }

    .item-circle-block__items._active {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      color: #ffffff;
      background: #161616;
      margin: 30px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
  
  @keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(1turn);
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="sector-two__description description-sector-two">
   <div class="item-circle__scene">
     <div data-id="1" class="item-circle__circle circle_1"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-circle-block__items">
     какой-то текст
   </div>
   <div class="item-circle__scene">
     <div data-id="2" class="item-circle__circle circle_2"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-circle-block__items">
     какой-то текст
   </div>
   <div class="item-circle__scene">
     <div data-id="3" class="item-circle__circle circle_3"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-circle-block__items">
     какой-то текст
   </div>
 </div>
```